# Acceder a un "user control" desde un formulario principal (runtime)

Tags: c#, usercontrol

Tengo un formulario principal que tiene incrustado un "User control" incorporado a través del diseñador de visual studio.

El "User control" tiene a su vez un componente iGrid "10Tec" #10tec también agregado  por el diseñador.

Lo que necesito y no logro hacer es agregar filas al grid desde el formulario principal.

Desde el formulario si hago esto no funciona porque estoy instanciando un nuevo control y lo que yo necesito es acceder al que ya está incorporado a traves del diseñador.

```
new CtrDetail().FillGrid(item);
```

Si el método FillGrid lo hago estático para no instanciar otra vez el "User Control", el componente iGrid me arroja un error, ya que no es estático:

```
 public static void FillGrid(PrDetail prDetail)
      {
            iGRow myRow;
            myRow = GridDetails.Rows.Add();
            myRow.Cells[0].Value = prDetail.NroRow;
            myRow.Cells[1].Value = prDetail.Quantity;
            myRow.Cells[2].Value = prDetail.Product;
            myRow.Cells[3].Value = prDetail.Account_Id;
      }
```

https://prnt.sc/10wj8gf

Podría implementar una Interfaz pero el "control user" y el iGrid no tengo acceso al constructor porque fueron arrastrados y no instanciados programáticamente.

Se me ocurre agregar el Grid programáticamente pero el control iGrid ya está configurado con el diseñador y me tomaría mucho tiempo crearlo de nuevo:

```
iGrid iGrid2 = new iGrid();
        iGrid2.Cols.Count = 4;              
        foreach (PrDetail item in rows)
        {                
            myRow = iGrid2.Rows.Add();
            myRow.Cells[0].Value = item.NroRow;
            myRow.Cells[1].Value = item.Quantity;
            myRow.Cells[2].Value = item.Product;
            myRow.Cells[3].Value = item.Account_Id;
        }
        CtrDetail.panel1.Controls.Add(iGrid2); // Tuve que cambiar el modificador de Panel1 a: public.
```

Alguna otra solución que no sea agregar el iGrid en runtime. ¿?

Solución:
Finalmente puse el control Modifier=Public

Comment: Pero el user control es un control como cualquier otro. Si lo hiciste en el diseñador, tiene un nombre y se accede a sus propiedades como accederias a las propiedades de cualquier control. Si haces el metodo de tu user control publico, con [nombredelcontrol].metodo accedes como a cualquier metodo de cualquier control...

Comment: Normalmente, los componentes Grid tienen funciones como AcceptChanges, ya intentaste iGrid2.AcceptChanges(); al final de tu última línea (CtrDetail.panel1.Controls.Add(iGrid2);)?

Comment: @gbianchi Cuando accedo al grid y quiero agregarle filas no se dibujan. Debería poder acceder asi: Control.Grid.AddRows(); pero esto no me agrega nada al Grid, pero cuando lo dibujo en runtime y lo agrego al panel con las filas ya agregadas me funciona perfecto. pero no quiero agregar el grid así ya que tiene muchas columnas que configurar.

Comment: @jtaborga El grid de 10tec no tiene esos métodos. :(

Comment: Voy de vuelta. Tu control, es un objeto como cualquier otro. Si vos lo agregaste a tu form con el nombre "control", entonces en tu formulario hay una variable que se llama control y es justamente ese que agregaste. Despues, todo lo que hagas esta en el codigo que le pongas a tu control.

Comment: @jtaborga el user control lo agrego en el load del form principal. Mi app inicia un form principal que se le van agregando controles según el perfil del usuario. Este user control tiene a su vez un Grid. (El user control con el grid está creado con el diseñador). Luego quiero que al hacer click en el formulario principal se vayan agregando filas al grid que está en el user control.